# Group Theory - product of function periods

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $f : G \rightarrow G$ a function. Prove the set of all periods of $f$ is a subgroup. (A period is any $a \in G$ such that $\forall x \in G, f(ax) = f(x)$)

If we let $H$ be the subgroup of periods, I'm having difficulty proving that $H$ is closed with respect to products i.e. $a, b \in H \implies ab \in H$.

I've tried getting a contradiction if $ab$ is not in $H$ with no success.
I've also proved that each period, $a$, can be written as a product of two elements in $G$ but this tells us nothing about if these two elements are themselves a period. An answer or even suggestions are hugely welcome!

Yet another question from "A Book of Abstract Algebra" - C Pinter, a solution set would be helpful for people self-studying if anyone is aware of a full one.

Comment: $f(abx) = f(a(bx)) = f(bx) = f(x)$ for any $x\in G$. Also, if $x\in G$, then $x = a^{-1}y$ for $y\in G$, so $f(ax) = f(y) = f(x) = f(a^{-1}y)$, so $a^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: @Jakobian hey thank you for your answer, I looked over the fact $f(a(bx)) = f(bx)$ and tried to get from $f(abx) = f(x)$ directly. I assume with the same arugment this would extend to any length product $a_1a_2 \ldots a_n$, $a_i \in G$?

Comment: We've already shown that $a_1, a_2\in H$ implies $a_1a_2\in H$, going by induction we have easy consequence that $a_1...a_n\in H$, this is not really a property of this concrete example, but groups in general.